# What are the Screensharing in Messages requirements?

Tags: messages, screen-sharing

I used to be able to screen share with my cousin using Messages. It is now broken. What does he need on his end to get screensharing to work again? I have an AIM account setup in Messages on my Mac running the latest version of Mavericks. He has the same setup on his Mac. He doesn't have an AIM account, just an iCloud account. Does he need an AIM account, too?

He is logged into Messages with his iCloud account, but the screensharing option is dimmed and I cannot ask him to share his screen.

Thanks,
Walt

Comment: At some point I read that an AIM (AOL) account was required for screensharing in Messages for MacOS, that an iCloud account did not allow screensharing. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple those are the requirements for audio and video chats and screen sharing.

- Camera (video chatting)
- Microphone (audio and video chatting)
- Internet connection speed (upstream and downstream)

  > Share your screen or share a friend’s screen:  128 Kbps
- Mac OS X version of people you message
- Computer processor type of people you message

Source: [Messages (Mountain Lion): Requirements for audio chats, video chats, and screen sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12034)